# How to group count a node in an XML column in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have some XML data stored in a column in a SQL table that I need to get all the variables for one of the XML items group counted.

The query looks like this:

```
select fd.stdFormData 
from formdata fd   
where fd.FormType = '1X'
```

The returned data looks like this:

[image]

I need to group count the results of `treatmentDiscussed` to get something that looks like this:

[image]

I'm pretty novice at working with XML data in a SQL Server table, so any assistance on how to proceed I would be grateful for. Thanks in advance.

here is what I have so far as example. Unfortunatly I get a subquery error due to too may values returned

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

```
declare @Data XML ,
@treatmentReferrals varchar(50)   
select   @Data  =  (select  fd.Data from  formdata fd   where  fd.FormType  =  '1X' ) 
SELECT     @Data.value('(/root//treatmentDiscussed/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as treatmentDiscussed  
select  @treatmentReferrals = (SELECT     @Data.value('(/root//treatmentDiscussed/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as treatmentDiscussed )
 CREATE TABLE #Data
( 
treatmentReferrals VARCHAR(30) 
) 
INSERT INTO #Data (treatmentDiscussed)
VALUES (@treatmentDiscussed) 
 
 DROP TABLE #Data
```

Comment: Consumable sample data, not images, would help us help you.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have used XQuery to pull out the relevant value, a `GROUP BY` should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT
  v.stdFormData,
  COUNT(*) count
FROM formdata fd   
CROSS APPLY fd.stdFormData.nodes('root/treatmentDiscussed') x(td)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (td.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(10)'))) v(stdFormData)
WHERE fd.FormType = '1X'
GROUP BY
  v.stdFormData;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe3cbeba83a70368b9f8786df95dd108)

Comment: The OP didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. Unfortunately, the same issue is with your answer. It is impossible to copy it to SSMS, run it, test it, etc.

Comment: Given you fiddle, happy now?